# How to use decoration in RCP editor tab

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, eclipse-rcp

for my project I validate some code inside the editor.
In case of failure I would like to decorate the head of the editor-tabs like it is done in the eclipse-editors tab when the java compiler shows errors/warnings for the files.

Example:
[image: example for editor behavior]
How can I adapt this functionality?

We use eclipse rcp version 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your editor you can change the image by calling the

```
protected void setTitleImage(Image titleImage)
```

method. The is defined in `WorkbenchPart` which is a base class for editors.

You can use `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecorationOverlayIcon` to combine an overlay image with the main image.

```
Image image = ... base image ...

ImageDescriptor[] descriptors = new ImageDescriptor[5]

descriptors[IDecoration.BOTTOM_LEFT] = ... overlay image descriptor

Image decorated = new DecorationOverlayIcon(image, descriptors).createImage();
```

Comment: yes, but how can I use a decorating image with the title image, like the warnings icon in eclipse

Comment: Added DecorationOverlayIcon

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: How can I tell us that when you haven't given us any information about how your editor works.

Comment: thank you so much! The example with the descriptor was exactly what I needed. I was always looking at Decorators and that did not word. Thanks :)